# What value does ActiveRecords return when a column is NULL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm in a environment where I can't test it, and I don't find information or any example on internet.

Let's say I have a statement like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_values("select a from table_b where id = 'x'")
```

(I know that it's not recommended and it's better to use other ways to deal with the database)

If some rows have the column 'a' as NULL, what do I have in ruby? "NULL", Nil or another thing?

Comment: isn't it faster to check it manually rather that posting the question?

Comment: as I have said, I can't test it now

Comment: I think it will likely be `nil`, but I can see how some drivers/adapters, with certain configuration, could return empty strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby only has one value for nothing which is `nil`. This is one thing that Matz got absolutely right compared to other languages.

A NULL value in SQL is mapped to `nil` by the adapter in most cases.

If you have a column default which is not nil (say "" or 0 for example) the result will not be nil since nothing is equatable to nil in Ruby (unlike some very popular but poorly designed languages).

```
irb(main):003:0> nil == ""
=> false
irb(main):004:0> nil == 0
=> false
irb(main):005:0> nil == false
=> false
irb(main):006:0> !!nil
=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

With ActiveRecord its most likely to depend on the database you have. I did try your query and with Postgres database it shows `[]`empty array or `[2,3]` if the return has id of 2 and 3. Please feel free to share database type.

Comment: That does not really prove anything since the id column obviously is not NULL.

Comment: The database is MySQL